How to convert AdMob `GADFullScreenContentDelegate` to Swift 6 concurrency
This is a similar problem to How to convert `VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate` to Swift 6 Concurrency but one warning is new, so this may require different solution.
I have the following code:
@MainActor
final class InterstitialWrapper: NSObject {
  ...
}

extension InterstitialWrapper: GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
  func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
    
  }
  ... 

I got this error:

Main actor-isolated instance method 'ad(_:didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError:)' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

Then I use @preconcurrency tag:
extension InterstitialWrapper: @preconcurrency GADFullScreenContentDelegate

The error becomes:

Non-sendable type 'any GADFullScreenPresentingAd' in parameter of the protocol requirement satisfied by main actor-isolated instance method 'ad(_:didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError:)' cannot cross actor boundary; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

Then I use @preconcurrency import:
@preconcurrency import GoogleMobileAds

Then I got:

'@preconcurrency' attribute on module 'GoogleMobileAds' has no effect

I have verified that this is the only file that imports GoogleMobileAds.
Note that this is similar to How to convert `VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate` to Swift 6 Concurrency, but the warning about Non-sendable type 'any GADFullScreenPresentingAd' is new. Also it's not a system framework but a 3rd party framework (admob). So I am creating a new question here in case the solution is different.

Until the old api updates to use MainActor (I hope this is what you're asking for) you can use assumeIsolated. That makes your app crash (better than not noticing it) if you dont run the function in the MainActor.
nonisolated func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
  MainActor.assumeIsolated {
    //Code Goes here
  }
}


Why the @preconcurrency trick doesn't work?

This assumeIsolated gives me a warning when I tried to access ad inside: "Sending 'ad' risks causing data races; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode".

@OMGPOP – If you @preconcurrency import GoogleMobileAds, it should silence the sendability warnings for ad.

@Rob it didn't work: '@preconcurrency' attribute on module 'GoogleMobileAds' has no effect

@OMGPOP – For me, in Xcode 15.4, making this nonisolated func ad(…) {…} and MainActor.assumeIsolated {…} was sufficient. In Xcode 16 Beta 3 in Swift 6 mode, I had to add @preconcurrency to the import GoogleMobileAds. What Xcode version are you using?

Version 16.0 beta 3 (16A5202i), with Swift 5 mode, but "Complete" checking
